# Which technology is best to develop web2.0? Flex,JavaFX and html5

Tags: apache-flex, html, javafx

I would like to know the html5 has the complete feature to develop the web2.0 and 
i want to know from these technology like flex, javafx and html5 which one will be the best to develop the web2.0?

Comment: There is no simple or widely accepted accepted answer to this question as stated. Please make it clearer and more specific if you expect to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Most sites commonly classified as "Web 2.0" are developed in [X]HTML, CSS, and Javascript.  However, the features that are associated with the term (user generated content, rich interfaces, api use & exposure, among other things) can be built in any of the technologies you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reach the most number of audience (including iPad users), then go for html/css/js.

As Brian mentioned Web 2.0 is normally characterized by mashups, social networking and mostly glossy icons. :)